# Introducing a sine half-angle substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

If you are a student of integral calculus, it is highly likely that you have come across or will come across the famous  [Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution), which is very useful for converting rational expressions involving trigonometric functions into ordinary rational expressions involving $t$, where $t=\tan{\frac12{x}}$. The general transformation formula is as follows:

> $$\int f(\sin{x},\cos{x})\,dx =  \int f\left(\frac{2t}{1+t^2}, \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\right)\frac{2dt}{1+t^2}.$$

For this question, I introduce another substitution as a companion to the Weierstrass substitution that can transform certain rational expressions of trigonometric functions into simpler ordinary rational expressions than the Weierstrass substitution. For instance, it would be useful when a common linear factor of $\sin{x}$ appears in the numerator or denominator of the integrand. The general transformation formula is given by:

> $$\int f(\sin{x},\cos{x})\,dx =  \int f(2\sqrt{s-s^2}, 1-2s)\frac{ds}{\sqrt{s-s^2}}.$$

Here $s=\sin^2{\frac12x}$.

**Derivation**

Using the double-angle formulas and the Pythagorean identity, one gets
$$\sin{x}=2\sin{\frac12x}\cos{\frac12x}=2\sin{\frac12x}\sqrt{1-\sin^2{\frac12x}}=2\sqrt{\sin^2{\frac12x}-\sin^4{\frac12x}}=2\sqrt{s-s^2},$$
$$\cos{x}=1-2\sin^2{\frac12x}=1-2s.$$
Finally, since $s=\sin^2{\frac12x}$, differentiation rules imply
$$ds=\sin{\frac12x}\cos{\frac12x}\,dx=\frac{\sin{x}}{2}\,dx,$$
and thus,
$$dx=\frac{ds}{\sqrt{s-s^2}}.$$

**Example 1**

By applying the sine half-angle substitution and simplifying,
$$\int \frac{\sin{x}}{\sin^2{x}+2\cos{x}}\,dx=\int \frac{1}{1-2s^2}\,ds.$$
Using [standard integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_functions#Standard_integrals),
$$\int \frac{1}{1-2s^2}\,ds=\frac{\tanh^{-1}{(\sqrt{2}s)}}{\sqrt{2}}+C=\frac{\tanh^{-1}{(\sqrt{2}\sin^2{\frac12x})}}{\sqrt{2}}+C.$$
The advantage of this substitution is evident when comparing it to the solution provided in this [integral calculator](https://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=sinx%2F%28sin%5E2x%2B2cosx) (which solution, by the way, is equivalent to the one given here) or when using the Weierstrass substitution.

**Example 2**

By applying the sine half-angle substitution,
$$\int \frac{1}{\sin^3{x}}\,dx=\frac18\int \frac{1}{(s-s^2)^2}\,ds.$$
Using partial fraction decomposition,
$$\frac18\int \frac{1}{(s-s^2)^2}\,ds=\frac18\int \left(\frac{1}{s}+\frac{1}{s^2}-\frac{2}{s-1}+\frac{1}{(s-1)^2}\right)\,ds=\frac14\ln{\left|\frac{s}{1-s}\right|}+\frac18\left(\frac{1}{1-s}-\frac{1}{s}\right)+C.$$
Substituting $s$ by $\sin^2{\frac12x}$, we have
$$\frac18\int \frac{1}{(s-s^2)^2}\,ds=\frac14\ln{\left|\tan^2{\frac12x}\right|}+\frac18\left(\frac{1}{\cos^2{\frac12x}}-\frac{1}{\sin^2{\frac12x}}\right)+C=\frac12\left(\ln{|\tan{\frac12x}|}-\frac{\cos{x}}{\sin^2{x}}\right)+C.$$
A solution using integration by parts is given at [Integrals For You](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q55UjdCe9tg).

**Is this substitution well-known?** At least I haven't found it on the Internet.

Comment: In examples $1$ and $2$  substitution $t=\cos x$ leads immediately to rational functions. I do not see the advantage of applying half angle.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc: In example 1, $t=\cos{x}$ quickly leads us to a rational expression, but then you have to perform partial fraction decomposition. That substitution is not more immediate than mine.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc: In example 2, we would have to see which of the two rational expressions obtained is easier to solve using the substitution you suggest or the sine half-angle substitution. The point is not merely to arrive at a rational expression. The solutions I have seen online use integration by parts or the reduction formula.

Comment: I agree, but I do not see the advantage of asubstitution which makes impression of a master key.

Comment: @Ryszard: The statement you provided is indeed self-contradictory. It states, **"I do not see the advantage of a substitution which makes an impression of a master key."** This implies that the substitution appears to have the characteristics of a master key but lacks any actual advantage.

Since the statement acknowledges the impression of a master key, it suggests that the substitution possesses qualities that make it appear advantageous. However, then you claim not to see any advantage in using it. A contradiction!

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$2s=2 \sin^2\frac x2 = 1-\cos x$$
So, the sine half-angle substitution is effectively the substitution $t=-\cos x$ plus $1$.